# MongoDB ISODate query with PHP

Tags: php, mongodb, isodate, mongodate

I am trying to retrieve data from mongo collection based on date, I want to get data where the date is greater or equal to the present day's date (i.e. the date under the data field). However I can't seem to understand why my query returns nothing (empty mongo object). Below is my code:

Array struct/content:

```
{ 
"_id" : ObjectId("990093409187049704809d"), 
"type" : "number 1 champion", 
"entryDate" : ISODate("2016-05-12T10:55:55.000+0000"), 
"requester" : {
    "cn" : "Torgue", 
    "username" : "tg"
}, 
"data" : {
    "office" : "Badass Crater of Badassitude",  
    "name" : {
        "firstname" : "Salvador", 
        "middlename" : "A", 
        "surname" : "Gunzerker"
    }, 
    "date" : ISODate("2016-05-23T23:00:00.000+0000"), 
}, 
"index" : "1"
}
```

PHP query:

```
$today =  date(DATE_ISO8601, (new MongoDate())->sec);
$str = $col1->find(array('type' => 'number 1 champion', 'data.date'=>array ('gte'=>$today))); 
print_r($str);
```

Please can anyone point me in the right direction or explain to me what to do in order to get the right output.

**For anyone who has same problem, below is the solution:**

```
$query = array('type' => 'number 1 champion', 'data.date'=>array ('$gte'=>new mongoDate()));
$str = $col1->find($query);
```

then loop to view results:

```
echo '<pre>';
foreach($str as $doc){
  print_r($doc);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use **MongoDate** object to query.

For current date you may use `new MongoDate()` which make MongoDate initialize with current Date

If you want to pass some custom Date you may use strtotime to convert String to Date type

```
$stringtime = "2016-04-09 00:00:00"

$inputdate = strtotime($stringtime)
```

and then finally passing it to MongoDate contructor to get relevant object.

```
new MongoDate($inputdate)
```

refer [PHP Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongodate.php)

Comment: @JustIce looks like you have the solution now, and it looks like the problem was same.
the new MongoDate() will give object with current date 
new MongoDate(strtotime($inputDate)) you have and option of using some $inputDate which can be a String with Date Format .

I have updated my answer for a more clear view

Answer (score 0):

For those who landed here through the search, as I did, a current solution (2021) can be found here in the meantime: https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mongodb-bson-utcdatetime.php

Please note the first comment with the milliseconds. Maybe it will save you time when troubleshooting ;-)